# Intelligent code suggestion by Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I am evaluating Intellij Idea 13.1 Ultimate edition on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I tested code suggestion in my JSP page for possible JSTL tags, but Intellij Idea does not give me any useful suggestion (see the screenshot).

[image]

But I did the same with my Netbeans IDE and it gave me excellent suggestions (see the screenshot).

[image]

Is it the natural behaviour of Intellij Idea or I am missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add JSTL library to the class path. You can download it from maven repository.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

[JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)